# How to use LibGDX?

Tags: java, android, animation, unity-game-engine, libgdx

I am just getting started with coding and app development using LibGDX and i´ve got some general and some more specific questions about it.

Before I start: I know that some of my questions might have already been asked somewhere on the internet but I found it really hard to get a straight answer to them.

**So, the most basic question first:**

Is it possible to create an average application (like angry birds or doodle jump) in LibGDX in a reasonable amount of time? 
Browsing the internet I came across many people stating that engines like Unity are "just so much easier to use" and that you can create a game in a fraction of the time it would take you to code a game in LibGDX.
Is that really the case?

**My second question connects to the first:**

Is LibGDX really worth the time? Picking up any engine or Framework seems like a lot of work, so I wondered if LibGDX is a growing platform worth learning or just an irrelevant framework of many.

**The third question is a bit more specific (and the most important one for me):**

How can I make LibGDX game pretty?
I know, that sounds weird at first but looking at hundreds of apps in all kind of appstores I´ve noticed that most unity apps look really neat whereas most apps found in the Badlogic gallery look just awful to be honest.

So I wondered is there a simple way to add animations, particle effects, shadows, etc. to a LibGDX application. If I was coding a 2048 clone (just as an example) how can I make my tiles slide together and blend nicely?

Creating good looking animations is something I struggle with the most...

([If you want you can have a look at what I created](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.libGDX.falling.android))

I would really appreciate any answer to any of my questions!
Thank you for making it through this huge post.

MrMorph

Comment: For a complete beginner in game programming, I would estimate Unity could save you 30-40% of your time because you won't run into some of the common beginner issues that you do without a WYSIWYG view of what you're working on. Once you've been through the gamut of "gotchas" that time savings will shrink quite a bit. I've used both engines and there are pros and cons. There is a WYSIWYG for LibGDX called Overlap2D, which might fix those shortcomings, though. If I were doing a large scale game I would probably pick Unity for the sake of easier cross-platform maintainability.

Comment: For a simple 2D game, I would still pick LibGDX because it was designed for 2D from the beginning. A couple of years ago, to do 2D properly in Unity, you needed a complete solution for sprite atlases and GUI components because the built in stuff was garbage. I know they've worked a lot on that since then, but I haven't tried the new version yet. I used a paid third party plugin for the 2D functionality I needed.

Comment: I think possibly the reason you see a lot of amateurish games made with LibGDX is because Unity was not free until a couple years ago. People who were more than hobbyists were probably interested in making money, and so went with game engines that work on iPhone. LibGDX's wasn't always iOS compatible, whereas Unity  was, as well as cocos2d-x (free). It is certainly possible to make something professional looking. Look up Space Grunts, Ingress, Double Helix Live Wallpaper, Kraken Live Wallpaper, Asteroids Pack Live Wallpaper, and Huey.

Answer (score 0):

**Question 1:**

If you're good at LibGDX and know quite a bit about the API, it would be easy to make a game like Angry Birds or Doodle Jump. Unity is easier to use, because GDX doesn't have a GUI editor - meaning you have to position things using coordinates.

**Question 2:**

I think LibGDX is worth doing. It's free and royalty-free, which is good unlike Unity, and it's on Java so it's relatively fast.

**Question 3:**

To make particles, there's a 2D and 3D particle editor which you can download of the LibGDX website or run from your IDE if you import the 'tools' module. For animations, you can make sprite-sheet animations easily with the `Animation` class and you can move things around smoothly (for your 2048 clone) using functions like `MathUtils.lerp()` to smoothly interpolate a value to another, over time, slowing down as it gets nearer.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!
Seems like your in favor of LibGDX ;)
I didn´t know interpolation was possible, will try it out asap :)

Comment: You can use overlap2D for a GUI to build levels. It's a standard 3th party library integrated in the setup file.

Answer (score 0):

A late answer, but hopefully someone will find this useful.

Checkout my answer to a similar question here: [What I need to get android game with graphics like this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42474144/what-i-need-to-get-android-game-with-graphics-like-this/43195305?noredirect=1#comment73553703_43195305)
I've used both libgdx and Unity and talk about my experience in the answer. At this point I'm in favor for Unity for most small/medium sized games. The editor really does make development much easier (especially for a one-man team). Libgdx + Overlap2D + Ashley (entity component system) is basically a very light-weight version of unity imo. Going the open-source route, you will definitely learn more since you'll be more involved in gluing these tools/concepts together. To answer your individual questions directly:

**Question 1:**

There are many good games made with libgdx. The reason you see a lot of crappy looking games in Gallery is because the submissions are sorted by time. The gallery does not prioritize good games to be shown first, this was a community decision a while back. Engines like Unity of course show off the best games first. To see some good looking libgdx games, checkout games by [Robotality](http://robotality.com/blog/). Also, take a look at the "[Showcase](http://www.badlogicgames.com/forum/viewforum.php?f=16)" section of libgdx forums; sorting by reply count will show some interesting games made in past few years.

As for the the claims that Unity is easier to use, I agree. I've made the switch myself just because how easy it is to come back to a project after months, and just starting playing around with it. Not as easy when your game is mostly code.

**Question 2:**

Libgdx is the better way to go if you want to learn. Because it's a framework, you'll be dealing more closely with the components that make up a game engine. You'll be putting your own game engine together with the APIs provided. Unlike Unity, you'll have to choose whether you want to use an Entity Component System like Ashly. You'll decide when physics engines get updated, when you render, how you load and manage assets, etc. Once again, unlike Unity, there is no enforced structure in place.

You'll be spending time reading libgdx's very well written source code as well as the excellent technical github documentation. I'd say the overall effort to make a game is greater when using libgdx, because of the learning. It's great if you have the time, but can be frustrating if you're developing only once in a while as a hobby.

**Question 3:**

The question is a little unclear. As I've stated above, there are plenty of crappy looking games made with unity, they just don't show them on their gallery/showcase game. Plenty of games with bad art are made with all popular game engines.

Libgdx has the things you want: checkout Interpolation functions for smoothly controlling object movements, particle editor to create & load particles, not sure about shadows (for 3D?).

Hope this will help someone decide what tool to use.

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes it is very possible to create a simple game in `libgdx`. I used to use this framework all the time. If you are semi new to it YouTube has some awesome tutorials.
   Now I use unity primarily, and here is why:

   - It is easier from a productivity standpoint yes.
   - Libgdx can be a lot of work when trying to work with graphics.
   - Plus it was an easy transition from Java to c#.
   - And yes in most cases unity can move a bit faster, again from a productivity standpoint, in libgdx there is more of a process to setting up graphics and viewports and etc.
2. libgdx is 100% worth it. A big part of what libgdx helped me with was grasping how the backed of these applications work. This has helped me a great deal in debugging problems in unity and just advancing my knowledge overall.
3. If you have good graphics and understanding of the framework then you can make a libgdx game that does look beautiful. The difference is that unity simplifies the process for you. And all the demos you see are from a huge pool of projects. With libgdx being such a good start to game development, there are going to be plenty of projects, with no proof of how much work and or time was put in.