# What I need to get android game with graphics like this?

Tags: android, canvas, graphics

I've created a few android apps but using just regular layouts and views. 
Now I am trying to learn a game developing and I understand that I need to use either custom drawings to canvas or open gl to get better graphics and performance.
I just can't quite figure out where to start. 
For example, to get graphics like this (see attachments) is drawing to canvas is enough, or should I learn Open GL, or is it only achievable with things like unity or libgdx?

[image]
[image]

Comment: You need a designer

Comment: Straightforward answer: You need a graphics designer.

Comment: I can draw all this no problem. It's not the question I asked ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like a pretty straightforward game. A few images, a few animations to move them around, and possibly some particle effects (celebration fireworks, etc). You would get the images and then use a game engine like unity or a framework like libgdx or monodevelop.

I have experience with both Unity and libgdx (which is similar to monodevelop and XDA). I would suggest you use unity just because of the editor. This is something that I think isn't mentioned as much in the unity vs libgdx comparisons. The unity editor will allow you to prototype the game visually MUCH quicker than using a code-focused environment like libgdx. There is an open source editor for libgdx called Overlap2D but it of course doesn't have nearly as many features. For loading the scene from the editor into your game it's using an entity component system (just like unity) called Ashley. In similar to unity and is basically mimicking it.

I would recommend using libgdx only if you're an experienced developer and require the level of low level control libgdx provides, or if you just want to learn. It's good to learn and get experience with working at a lower level, such as managing the game loop and assets yourself.

Also some recommend unity only for 3D games. This was the case couple years ago, but now they have official 2D support, so it's pretty good for 2D games now. The editor works the same as for 3D games. They even have a 2D physics editor built in (assigning colliders to images, creating joints between colliders, etc).

Comment: Thanks for your comment.
Since I posted the question I spent my time looking into Unity and libgdx.
As Java is my primary language I wanted to stay with it and tried libgdx. After reading some tutorials and watching videos, I think I had an idea how to put what I wanted together, but very little progress. Overlap2D seemed like a good tool but just like you said is nothing compare to what Unity has to offer. And it seemed to me that I was spending time trying to figure out how to do what I wanted to do rather than actually doing it.

Comment: On the other hand, with Unity in just a few hours I had my UI done with buttons and animation the way I wanted it. As I already have all my logic done in Java I just need to adjust it to Unity and learn how to do it in C# which, I think, will be more productive and rewarding.

As someone who never had any expirience with either of them I must say I had better progress with Unity, even tho I had no previous experience with C#.

Sorry it was too long so I had to slplit it in two parts.

Comment: Glad to hear it worked out! I've had the same experience going from libgdx+Overlap2D to Unity. I've published a small math game using Overlap2D and made my initial 2D bike game prototype using it. The combination is definitely functional, but I couldn't prototype quickly; mostly because my physics model was done entirely in code (~400 lines). Then I switched to Unity2D and re-implemented the whole thing in a day with the built-in 2D physics editor. The only thing I miss from libgdx is the forum community and that it's open-source. It's neat to be able to read some really good code to learn :)